# Create a dictionary with name of variable

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I am trying to write a program to parse a file, break it into sections, and read it into a nested dictionary. I want the output to be something like this:

```
output = {'section1':{'nested_section1':{'value1':'value2'}}}
```

I'm trying to do this by building separate dictionaries, than merging them, but I'm running into trouble naming them. I want the dictionaries inside of the others to be named based on the sections of the file they're taken from. But it seems I can't name a dictionary from a variable.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but if you got `name = 'section1'`, then `{name: {'nested_section1':{'value1':'value2'}}}` will result in the same value as `output`.

Comment: Very difficult to gather what you are asking for w/o the code and sample input

Comment: Yes please post an example piece of code that's throwing an error so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: The only variable name shown in your example is `output`, yet the dictionary associated with it doesn't contain the string `"output"` -- so your question makes little sense as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can name a dictionary entry from a variable. If you have

```
text = "myKey" # or myNumber or any hashable type
data = dict()
```

You can do

```
data[text] = anyValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Store *all* your dictionaries in a single root dictionary.

```
all_dicts['output'] = {'section1':{'nested_section1':{'value1':'value2'}}}
```

As you merge dictionaries, remove the children from `all_dicts`.

```
all_dicts['someotherdict']['key'] = all_dicts['output']
del all_dicts['output']
```